# Cannot push git repo from within Python

Tags: python, git

I'm writing a [CLI-based web server control panel](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton) in Python 3 as a replacement for [Plesk](http://sp.parallels.com/products/plesk/). One of the functions of the application is to create and configure Git repositories in existing project directories. Interestingly, I can perform all Git functions using `os.system()` except for `git push -u origin master`. Here is the relevant code:

```
external_command = " cd %s ; " % (dir_name, )
external_command+= " git push -u origin master "
os.system(external_command)
```

This is the result:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, running the exact same command on the CLI results in success:

```
$ cd /var/www/foobar.com ; git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 190, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (185/185), done.
Writing objects: 100% (190/190), 1.36 MiB, done.
Total 190 (delta 131), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://alpha/var/git/foobar.com.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

**What might be the cause of this issue? How should I proceed to troubleshoot?** Note that the command in question is **the last command run** so the issue cannot be that other steps have yet to complete. The entire relevant function is `add_dir_to_git()` in [this file (Github link)](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton/blob/master/configure_system.py), copied here as well:

```
def add_dir_to_git():

    print('\nAdd Git repo.\n')

    dir_name = input('Directory path to add' + environment.prompt)
    git_name = input('Git repo path' + environment.prompt)
    # TODO: Validate input

    if not dir_name.endswith('/'):
        dir_name += '/' 

    if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
        print('The specified directory does not seem to exist: %s' % (dir_name, ))
        print('Aborting operation.')
        return False

    external_command = "cd %s ; " % (dir_name, )
    external_command+= " git status 2>&1 "

    git_check = os.popen(external_command).read().strip()

    if not 'Not a git repository' in git_check:
        print('The specified directory is already in a Git repository: %s' % (dir_name, ))
        print('Aborting operation.')
        return False

    external_command = " find %s -name '.git' -type d " % (dir_name, )
    subdirectory_git = os.popen(external_command).read().strip().split('\n')
    subdirectory_git = [x for x in subdirectory_git if x!='']

    if len(subdirectory_git)>0:
        print("Git directories were found in the following subdirectories:")
        for dirname in subdirectory_git:
            print(" * %s" % (dirname, ))

        continue_install = input("Continue? [y/N]" + environment.prompt).lower()

        if not continue_install=='y' and not continue_install=='yes':
            print('Aborting operation.')
            return False

    git_version = os.popen("git --version | awk '{print $3}'").read().strip().split('.')

    if git_version[0]=='1' and git_version[1]=='9':
        push_default = " git config push.default simple ; "
    else:
        push_default = ''

    external_command = "cd %s ; " % (dir_name, )
    external_command+= " git init ; "
    external_command+= " git config user.name 'Do not work on the server' ; "
    external_command+= " git config user.email 'do_not_work@on.the.server' ; "
    external_command+= push_default
    external_command+= " git add . ; "
    external_command+= " git commit -am 'Initial commit' 2>&1 "

    create_repo = os.popen(external_command).read().strip()

    #TODO: Check!

    git_config_file = dir_name + '.git/config'
    git_config = open(git_config_file, 'a')

    git_append = """ 
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = %s
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
""" % (git_name, )

    git_config.write(git_append)

    # TODO: Check that the steps completed properly.

    print('Done! If connecting to A NEW PUBLIC REPO then you must do an initial branch-configuration push. Would you like to do that now?')
    initial_push = input('[y/N]' + environment.prompt).lower()

    if initial_push=='y' or initial_push=='yes':
        external_command = " cd %s ; " % (dir_name, )
        external_command+= " git push -u origin master "
        os.system(external_command)

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the python sh module.. It allows you to import commands as functions. This is better than using os.system and more foolproof.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh

Then you can simply do:

```
from sh import git, cd
cd(dir_name)
git("push -u origin master")
```

Comment: Is it more foolproof than `subprocess`? How does it split the command into arguments?

Comment: I'm not the developer for this plugin but yes it should be more foolproof. I quote from the docs: "Note that these aren’t Python functions, these are running the binary commands on your system dynamically by resolving your $PATH, much like Bash does. In this way, all the programs on your system are easily available to you from within Python."

Comment: If I cannot find a way to resolve the issue by running the commands via `os.system()` and `os.popen()` then I will try `sh`. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen, I'll recommend using the `subprocess` module rather than os.system()..  It's dedicated and meant for executing system commands.

Comment: This answer did not resolve the issue of `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository`, and the `subprocess` did not help. either. I'm stumped.